# Are shabbat candlesticks on a tray muktzeh?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

If candlesticks are on a tray can they be moved off the table on Shabbat?

Comment: http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=746

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The candlesticks - if lit before shabbas and stay lit into shabbas  - remain muktzeh and cannot be moved for the entire shabbas. (One may ask a non-jew to remove them if the place is needed).

If the tray is designated for the candlesticks then the tray is considered a bosis (base for mukzteh) and is muktzeh for the duration of shabbas. Even if the candlesticks were removed somehow the tray remains muktzeh and can not be moved.

See Igros Moshe [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=117).

Comment: This is what I had been taught. I was told the Shulcan Aruch said the tray could me moved, but they didn't have the references. Thank you

Comment: But the tray cannot be moved

Comment: Sry if I wasn't clear ,I edited the answer

Comment: Nope you are clear. Both the tray and the candlesticks are muktzeh.

Comment: Your question is referring to moving them after the flame goes out right,since there is a discussion if one can move a tray with lit candles?

Comment: On a side note if you happen to be Sefardic there is a Shulchan Aruch 279:4 which allows a stipulation (it is best to ask a Rav since there is a lot on this specific topic) אם התנה מערב שבת על נר זה שיטלטלנו משיכבה מותר לטלטלו אחר שכבה. הגה: ויש אומרים דלא מהני תנאי וכן נוהגין במדינות אלו ודין התנאי עיין לקמן סימן תרל''ח (הגהות אשירי פרק כירה ורבינו ירוחם חלק ב' וכל בו) ונוהגין לטלטלו על ידי אינו יהודי ואין בזה משום איסור אמירה לאינו יהודי הואיל והמנהג כך הוי כאלו התנה עליו מתחלה ושרי. כן נראה לי:

Comment: I am not the person who mentioned it might be. Todah